# Comparing a field in a List of objects with a List of Strings in Drools

Tags: drools, mvel

Assume I have a `Policy`  object in Drools, that object contains a `List` of `Cover` objects, called `covers` and a `List` of `String` objects, which are called `requestedCovers`.

The `Cover` object contains `type` field, which is a `String` object.

I want to fire a rule if a requestedCover does not match a type in the Covers list.

```
rule "Add validation error for policies with requested covers that are not available"
when
    $p: Policy(available == true, $requestedCovers: requestedCovers, $covers: covers)
    $requestedCover: String() from $requestedCovers
    Cover(type not contains $requestedCover) from $covers 
then
    log.error("RHS rule not implemented yet. Found type {}.", $requestedCover);
end
```

However this seems to trigger every Cover is the covers list.

How to create this rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out, thanks to @laune for the help

```
when
    $p: Policy(available == true, $requestedCovers: requestedCovers, $covers: covers)
    $requestedCover: String() from $requestedCovers
    $coverTypes: List(!this.isEmpty()) from accumulate(Cover($coverType: type) from $covers; collectList($coverType))
    eval(!$coverTypes.contains($requestedCover))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two lists in this unwieldy object, and one of them is a cut of another list. What you need is the set of `requestedCovers - covers.type` (a set difference).

It's a cinch to write the set difference as a method, either in Policy or (as a static) in a separate utility class.

If you insist on Drools, you'll have to

```
rule x
when
  Policy( available, $reqs: requestedCovers, $covs: covers )
  accumulate( Cover( $type: type ) from $covs;
              $covered: collectSet( $type ) )
  $s: String( this not memberOf $covered ) from $reqs
then
  ...$s is not covered...
end
```

Untested!

Comment: Okay. Looks promissing. It first complained about `mismatched input 'not' in rule`. After changing `not in` to `not memberOf`. Now it is complaining about `Unknown property: type`. Any idea?

Comment: OK, sorry, I fixed the `not in`. -  But if `type` isn't known, I cannot see why. Does class Cover contain a `public String getType()`?

Comment: Yes. Case has a String getType() accessor method.

Comment: `Case` or `Cover`?

Comment: Sorry I meant `Cover`.

Comment: I guess then we are down to: please provide a full set of code reproducing the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Let me look into it first. I agree that it's a stange error, so I'll look if I can pinpoint it a bit further down.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Figured it out, see my answer.

Comment: And now it is not complaining about `type` being unknown? That's very strange.